# How do I set screen resolution for a specific program?

Tags: 14.04, display, resolution, screen

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I wish to force a specific program to run at a predetermined screen resolution and have the screen return to my default resolution after closing the program. The program is the [Brackets text editor](http://brackets.io/) and the extensions manager is not shown completely when I run Brackets at 1024*768, as seen below in the picture.

[image: Extensions manager truncated due to screen resolution]

It displays well at 1280*1024 but it is very uncomfortable to my eyes.

Here is my `xrandr` command output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1024 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
VGA1 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 255mm   
   1600x1200      74.8      
   1280x1024      85.0     75.0      
   1024x768       85.0     75.1*    70.1     60.0      
   1024x768i      87.1     
   832x624        74.6      
   800x600        85.1     72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2      
   640x480        85.0     75.0     72.8     66.7     60.0               
   720x400        87.8     70.1   
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Please explain with more details the case, why do you need to do that?

Comment: could you mention the program in question, the output of `xrandr` and the desired resolution?

Comment: Just edited my question !

Comment: I know that brackets is build mainly with html and css .. if just I can hack the code and edit it  that will be another way to do it but I don't know how to start

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following python script to start your application at a given resolution:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
import re
import subprocess
import sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--output', required=True)
parser.add_argument('--resolution', required=True)
parser.add_argument('APP')
args = parser.parse_args()

device_context = ''    # track what device's modes we are looking at
modes = []             # keep track of all the devices and modes discovered
current_modes = []     # remember the user's current settings

# Run xrandr and ask it what devices and modes are supported
xrandrinfo = subprocess.Popen('xrandr -q', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = xrandrinfo.communicate()[0].decode().split('\n')

for line in output:
    # luckily the various data from xrandr are separated by whitespace...
    foo = line.split()

    # Check to see if the second word in the line indicates a new context
    #  -- if so, keep track of the context of the device we're seeing
    if len(foo) >= 2:  # throw out any weirdly formatted lines
        if foo[1] == 'disconnected':
            # we have a new context, but it should be ignored
            device_context = ''
        if foo[1] == 'connected':
            # we have a new context that we want to test
            device_context = foo[0]
        elif device_context != '':  # we've previously seen a 'connected' dev
            # mode names seem to always be of the format [horiz]x[vert]
            # (there can be non-mode information inside of a device context!)
            if foo[0].find('x') != -1:
                modes.append((device_context, foo[0]))
            # we also want to remember what the current mode is, which xrandr
            # marks with a '*' character, so we can set things back the way
            # we found them at the end:
            if line.find('*') != -1:
                current_modes.append((device_context, foo[0]))

for mode in modes:
    if args.output == mode[0] and args.resolution == mode[1]:
        cmd = 'xrandr --output ' + mode[0] + ' --mode ' + mode[1]
        subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
        break
else:
    print('Unable to set mode ' + args.resolution + ' for output ' + args.output)
    sys.exit(1)

subprocess.call(args.APP, shell=True)

# Put things back the way we found them
for mode in current_modes:
    cmd = 'xrandr --output ' + mode[0] + ' --mode ' + mode[1]
    subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

Save the above script (e.g as `my-script.py`) and make it executable:

```
chmod +x my-script.py
```

To set a resolution of `1280x1024` and start `gedit` just type:

```
./my_script.py --output VGA1 --resolution 1280x1024 gedit
```

To avoid typing this command everytime, save the script in your home directory and add the following lines to your `.bashrc`:

```
alias my_bracket='~/my_script.py --output VGA1 --resolution 1280x1024 gedit'
```

Or even better, modify the desktop file that the package installs in `/usr/local/share/applications/brackets.desktop`.

```
sudo gedit /usr/local/share/applications/brackets.desktop
```

And replace the file content with the new lines below:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Brackets
Type=Application
Categories=Development
Exec=/home/mushir/my_script.py --output VGA1 --resolution=1280x1024 /opt/brackets/brackets
Icon=brackets
MimeType=text/html;
Keywords=Text;Editor;Write;Web;Development;
```

Source: [Checkbox xrandr_cycle script](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~checkbox-dev/checkbox/trunk/view/head:/providers/plainbox-provider-checkbox/bin/xrandr_cycle)

Comment: thanks .. but there is two issues about this script : every time  I need to run this command and this not very convenient for me and after I close the program  my screen doesn't go back automatically to the default    resolution

Comment: @Misho21: I've fixed the settings recovery issue

Comment: thanks now it's working ! I wonder if there is away to start this script automatically every time I run the program so it won't be necessary to run it from terminal every time ?

Comment: @Misho21: Please check my new edit

Comment: there is .bashrc file in home and another one in /etc tell me which one to edit please

Comment: @Misho21: Forget the (home)  `.bashrc` update and prefer the   `.desktop` if you're not starting `brackets` from a terminal

Comment: one last request I promise ! can I use this script to force Plymouth resolution ??

Comment: @Misho21: You can't, plymouth operates earlier in the boot process and uses itw own configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

Not using ubuntu here (Gentoo person), but look for package xrandr. Usually you can use things like

```
xrandr --output VGA-1 --mode 640x480
```

to change resolution and

```
xrandr --output VGA-1 --preferred
```

will put you back to default resolution.

```
xrandr
```

without options will give you display names and resolutions.

Just saw previous script version also use xrandr :). But maybe you can still find the information useful. Read in the manual pages for option tweaking

```
man xrandr
```